# SSRS Charts data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have situation where I need to create a column chart.

I have a field NotificationLog.Duedate . With this due date I need to create a chart with various condition.

I need to calculate the count of rows with conditions like below

- NotificationLog.Duedate < Present date
- NotificationLog.Duedate > Present date & NotificationLog.DueDate-Present date < 8 days
- NotificationLog.Duedate > Present date & NotificationLog.DueDate-Present date > 8 days

Using the above counts I need to create a column Chart which with the three categories in X axis and Days marked in Y axis.

As of now I get the NotificatonLog.Duedate in a dataset with several other columns . How Can i proceed from this point and accomplish my requirement .

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up an approriate expression-based field to group on.

I have a simplified Dataset to replicate your issue:

[image]

I have added a **Calculated Field** to the Dataset, called `DuedateGroup`:

[image]

The expression is:

```
=Switch(Fields!Duedate.Value < Today(), "Overdue"
    , Fields!Duedate.Value > Today() and Fields!Duedate.Value < DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 8, Today()), "Near Due"
    , Fields!Duedate.Value > Today() and Fields!Duedate.Value > DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 8, Today()), "Far Due")
```

i.e. the three groupings you require.

Now you can just use the new field in the Chart:

[image]

[image]

Looks OK to me.

If you didn't want to set up a Calculated Field, you could add the group expression directly into the Category Group at the Chart level, but I like the Calculated Field option.

Comment: Did this help with your issue at all?